# Javascript code is not working in my Android app

Tags: javascript, android, html, uiwebview

I write a `javascript` function to validate HTML5 components and embeds this web page with my android app using web view. But script is not working.

Following is the android code i have used.

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_web, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
  settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Write these two lines before loadUrl() method in your code and you are done.Hope it will help.

Comment: Its still not working. It is not giving any error bt not working properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this  in place of `javaScriptEnable`

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
  WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());       
  webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
  webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html"); 

//  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//  wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
//  wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```